# Reverse all words in array without the first one

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to get the following code works, so if the

> Input is: How are you dude?

Output should be:

> How era uoy edud?

I think that I am very close to finish it but I cannot understand why, the regular expression does not work it is not recognized.
Here is the repl: https://repl.it/MHzu/1

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Kata
{    
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          string str = Console.ReadLine();            
          string opaa = str;
          Match m = Regex.match(str,"(\w*) (\w.*)");
          string hoho = m.Groups[1];
          string strrev = "";
          foreach (var word in opaa.Split(' '))
          {
              string temp = " ";
              foreach (var ch in word.ToCharArray())
              {
                 temp = ch + temp;
              }
              strrev = strrev + temp + "";
          }
          Console.WriteLine(hohoo + strrev);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression?

Comment: Because I wanted to get the first word, well I just did like that if you have better solution, share it.

Comment: Divide & Conquer: If you have a solution for string[], you can split into string[0] and string[1..n], solve for second array and rejoin.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Linq too

```
string input = "think that I am very close to finish";

var  output = string.Join(" ",input.Split()
                                   .Select((x, i) => i == 0 ? x : string.Concat(x.Reverse())));
```

Comment: Sorry, but the very *example* `How are you dude?` is a *counter example*: expected `How era uoy edud?` actual `How era uoy ?edud` (please, notice the question mark `?`)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest `Regex.Replace` in order to extract and reverse *words only*:

```
  string src = "How are you dude?";

  // Side effect, which we usually should avoid
  int index = -1;

  // \p{L}+ - all Unicode letters
  string result = Regex.Replace(src, @"\p{L}+", match => ++index == 0
      ? match.Value
      : string.Concat(match.Value.Reverse()));

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome:

```
  How era uoy edud?
```

Please, notice that non-letter symbols (say, punctuation) are *preserved*; for the given

```
  srec = "Punctuations: comma, semicolon are in use!";
```

the outcome will be

```
  Punctuations: ammoc, nolocimes era ni esu!
```